# How to make vector-type-value to pinned memory in cuda

Tags: cuda

I have questions about making pinned memory.

Now I'm using CUDA to deal with great size of data.

To reduce run-time, I figure out it is necessary to make memory-copy and kernel-launch overlapped.

After searching some texts and web pages, to overlapping memory-copy and kernel-launch, I notice it is necessary to allocate host memory by using cudaMallocHost which will allocates host-memory to pinned memory.
In the case of using integer or array type on host, it was easy to make pinned memory.

Just like this...

```
cudaStream_t* streams = (cudaStream_t*)malloc(MAX_num_stream * sizeof(cudaStream_t));
for(i=0; i<MAX_num_stream; i++)
    cudaStreamCreate(&(streams[i]));

cudaMallocHost(&departure, its_size);

for(n=1; ... ; n++){
   cudaMemcpyAsync( ... streams[n]);
   kernel <<< ... , ... , ... , streams[n] >>> (...);
}
```

But in my case, my host departure memory is set by vertor type.

And I can't find anywhere the way to turn vector-type-host-memory into pinned memory by using cudaMallocHost.

Help me or give some advice to solve this problem.
Thanks you for reading my poor English. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vector type"? Do you mean the C++ `std::vector`, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I mean std::vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly, you can't allocate memory for anything other POD types using `cudaMallocHost`.

If you *really* need a `std::vector` which uses pinned memory, you will have to implement your own model of `std::allocator` which calls `cudaMallocHost` internally and instantiate your `std::vector` using that custom allocator.

Alternatively, the [thrust template library](http://thrust.github.com/) (which ships in recent releases of CUDA toolkit) includes an experimental pinned memory allocator which you could use with thrusts own vector class, which is iteself a model of `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks talonmies. This contents were helpful for my case.

Comment: And I have one more little question. Is it OK to use cudaMemcpyAsync and kernel without cudaMallocHost? I was trying to make Asynchronous code without making host pinned memory but this well worked. Is it general or accidental?

Comment: Yes it will work, but the transfers won't be asynchronous on the device for any transfer > 64kb. The host API call returns immediately, but the device is blocked until the copy completes, ie. no simultaneous kernel execution and memory copy or any other benefits of `cudaMemcpyAsync`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wondered it because measured run-time which used cudaMemcpyAsync and kernel without making pinned memory was little shorter than the case of not using cudaMemcpyAsync. Now I guess that was some transfer<64kb and this cause reducing run-time. Thanks for your kind reply.