# cudaMallocManaged with vector<complex<long double> > C++ - NVIDIA CUDA

Tags: c++, vector, cuda

I am in the process of implementing multithreading through a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M GPU for a simulation I have created. In order to make sure everything works properly, I have created some side code to test that everything works. At one point I need to update a vector of variables (they can all be updated separately).

Here is the gist of it:

```
`\__device__
int doComplexMath(float x, float y)
{
    return x+y;
}`

`// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y, vector<complex<long double> > *z)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
        z[i] = doComplexMath(*x, *y);
}`

`int main(void)
{
    int iGAMAf = 1<<10;
    float *x, *y;
    vector<complex<long double> > VEL(iGAMAf,zero);
    // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&x, sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&y, sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&VEL, iGAMAf*sizeof(vector<complex<long double> >));
    // initialize x and y on the host
    *x = 1.0f;
    *y = 2.0f;
    // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
    int blockSize = 256;
    int numBlocks = (iGAMAf + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
    add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(iGAMAf, x, y, *VEL);
    // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}`
```

I am trying to allocate unified memory (memory accessible from the GPU and CPU). When compiling using nvcc, I get the following error:

error: no instance of overloaded function "cudaMallocManaged" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::__1::vector, std::__1::allocator>> *, unsigned long)

How can I overload the function properly in CUDA to use this type with multithreading?

Comment: there are a number of defects in this code.  However, for the specific error you have identified, it's not possible to directly use a managed allocator with `std::vector`.  Instead, a straightforward approach would be to use a C-style array to store your data.  As a side note, you won't be able to use `std::vector` in kernel code either.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to do what you are trying to do.

To allocate a vector using managed memory you would have to write your own implementation of an allocator which inherits from [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) and calls `cudaMallocManaged` under the hood. You can then instantiate a `std::vector` using your allocator class.

Also note that your CUDA kernel code is broken in that you can't use `std::vector` in device code.

Note that although the question has managed memory in view, this is applicable to other types of CUDA allocation such as pinned allocation.

As another alternative, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453691/how-to-make-vector-type-value-to-pinned-memory-in-cuda), you could consider using a thrust host vector in lieu of `std::vector` and use a custom allocator with it.  A worked example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064383/how-to-asynchronously-copy-memory-from-the-host-to-the-device-using-thrust-and-c/25068346#25068346) in the case of pinned allocator (`cudaMallocHost`/`cudaHostAlloc`).